Time travelling paedo priest novel
I read this in the UK in the 1990s but it could have been older than that, I don't recall too much of the story.
Basically there's a priest who is a sexual predator to young boys, however he is selected (some demonical coercion) to go back to the middle ages and maybe solve a mystery.
He changes bodies with some medieval bishop on a pilgrimage and goes to a monastery for a night's shelter.
While there he demands a wash with bowls of hot water (suspicious back in the day) and also he wants some very young trainee monk to attend him.
This gets the Abbott involved and he bears witness to the travel dust washing and so thwarts the nefarious plans of the paedo priest.
Meanwhile the hapless bishop finds himself in modern (1980s?) times and under a geas...he is whimpering and praying on a tattoo table while something is inked on his chest.
He then fights temptation because some woman covered in tattoos strips in front of him and shows him her pierced nipples.
There are various shenanigans with the story flipping from the middle ages to modern times but I can't recall how it ends

The Priest by Thomas M. Disch.

In The Priest, Disch gives us an even more potent, darkly hypnotic, and fiendishly comic novel - a gothic romance like no other. At the center: Father Patrick Bryce, a Catholic priest with a present-day Minneapolis parish - and a pedophile past. He's spent time at a church-run retreat for priests of his persuasion and returned "rehabilitated": even better equipped to keep his vice active and hidden. Until the blackmail begins. It comes from three different sources (his own bishop being one), and each tops the next in imaginative proposals: Father Pat must head a militant (and probably illegal) anti-abortion campaign; Father Pat must apologize to each of his victims, face-to-face; Father Pat must read, and be ready to discuss, the work of a bizarre cult science fiction writer, and get the face of Satan tattooed on his chest. But the blackmailers and their demands are the least of Father Pat's problems. More dire is his increasingly incontrovertible sense that the nightmares in which he has been leading the life of a thirteenth-century bishop are not dreams at all. And that the Church, rife with corruption and scandal in both eras, is the only realistic sanctuary for him and his doppelganger, Bishop Silvanus de Roquefort, as they move - at once separately and together - through their own centuries-spanning maze of soul-killing horrors toward a distinctly hellish destiny.

Given the subject matter I'm going to be careful about quotes, but the scene where the bishop wakes in the tattoo parlour (to find his penis is being tattooed!) is relatively tame:

Silvanus knew almost as soon as he opened his eyes that he was in hell.
One minute he had been witnessing the interrogation of the heretic Aielot de Gaillac in the crypt of Notre Dame de Gevaudon, and the next he found himself strapped down to a pallet, much as Madame de Gaillac had been, while she, by a kind of infernal symmetry, had been transformed into a succubus or a female demon and was using an instrument of torture upon the exposed and anguished flesh of his male member. Her unbound breasts, which the interrogator had been about to cut from her body, remained intact, and now were covered with Satanic embroideries--images of serpents and flowers twined together, illuminating her flesh as if it were a living parchment. Her very flesh had become an emblem of an Eden fallen into the power of hell, where the serpent might live among the roses without the fear of God.
...
He had had one such vision before, on the feast day of Saint Macanus, following the accident in the sacristy when Abbé St-Loup had bled onto the white wool of the pallium, and he had found himself in this same chamber with his flesh being covered with the heraldry of hell. The man, or demon, whom he'd seen then and who so much resembled St-Loup, was present again, standing behind the succubus who was torturing him. The man's hands played with silver rings that hung from the pierced nipples of her painted breasts, like the rings placed in the snout of the pig, an animal symbolizing female lust. Her snout was beringed, as well, and each ear was a little marketplace of finely crafted silver. The Bishop almost forgot the pain he was suffering in the amazement of seeing Madame de Gaillac so bizarrely transfigured.

The tattoo artist is Delilah:

Madame de Gaillac laid down the instrument of torture while continuing to grasp his male member in her other hand. Both hands had bright red claws instead of fingernails. She smiled at him. "Hi. We were never formally introduced, but I know you're Damon. I'm Delilah."


Wow... I was not expecting such a rapid answer when I saw that question this morning.

I was quite a fan of Disch's novels in my younger days - even the pervy ones ;-)

Interesting find. I wonder what a "good ending" would be for this story, given the two very unlikeable protagonists... I find myself rooting for the demons.

I had no idea looking at the question, but in retrospect it does definitely sound like Disch.
